# Schubert cell of intersection of subspaces

Tags: schubert-calculus

Assume you are given two subspace $V$ and $W$, belonging to some Schubert cells $C_I$ and $C_J$. Is there an elementary closed form description of $V\cap W$ in $C_{I\cap J}$?

Here by "elementary" I mean everything is with respect to the standard flag, and thus the subspaces can be thought as column space of matrices of appropriate size, and $I, J$ are subsets of row/column indices.

Again, I am not looking for a description that involves, say, algebraic geometry language or other alikes.

Comment: What do you mean by $C_{I \cap J}$ ? And shouldn't $V \cap W$ depend on $V$ and $W$, not only on $C_I$ and $C_J$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course it will! And by $C_{I\cap J}$ I mean the cell that contains the intersection, though I now realize the confusion. I am simply asking for a description of the cell that contains $V\cap W$.